# MongoDB replSet exception

Tags: mongodb

i am new in MongoDB. I install MongoDB on Windows and I run the below script to set MongoDB replset.

[mongod --port 27017 --dbpath "D:\set up\mongodb\data" --replSet rs0]

But it throws exception as below:

[image]

Any help would be appreciate

Comment: You're in the `mongo` shell. Exit it to actually run things from your OS shell.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you! It's worked!!!